# Promise.all() behave very weirdly in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have encountered a very strange error while using Promises in NodeJS. I have an array that contains array of promises.

Example:

> let promises = [[P1, P2, P3], [P4, P5], [P6], [P7, P8], [P9, P10, P11,
>   P12, P13]]

Now if I feed the promises array to the following code, I expect each set of promises to be resolved **in order**.

```
(async () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
    console.log('Starting', i + 1, ' of ', promises.length, ' Total:',promises[i].length);
    await Promise.all(promises[i]).then(() => {
      console.log('Finished Section ', i + 1);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message);
    })
    console.log('Next Set of promises');
  }
  fs.appendFileSync('links.json', JSON.stringify(json));
})()
```

But thats not the case. The actually execution is,

**Step 1**: First Iteration starts

**Step 2**: All the promises in promises array get executed

**Step 3**: Once all the promises are resolved, the loop continues to the next iteration.

*Expected output: First set of promises resolve -> iterate -> second set of promises -> iterate and so on*

Am I missing something or does node execute Promises differently?

Comment: "*I expect each set of promises to be resolved in order*" then don't use `Promise.all`.

Comment: The promises inside the nested array can be in any order. I want to achieve batch processing.

Comment: sounds like you initiate all work early but later wait for each set to complete. Maybe you want to take one set, initiate all async task in that set, wait for it to finish with promise.all **then** take the next set of work to start and do all the work that needs to be done

Answer (score 3):

When you create a promise it calls the function you pass to it. That function determines when the promise resolves.

It could resolve before you store it in the `promises` variable. It could resolve much later.

**The important thing is that the clock starts ticking when the promise is created.**

Using `Promise.all` lets you run a function after all the promises you pass to it have resolved.

It won't prevent any other promises from resolving in the meantime.

---

Instead of storing the promises in your array, store the data that you want to work on (i.e. the input to the promises).

Start the promises inside the loop, and use `Promise.all` to wait for them all to resolve before starting the next set.

Comment: Your answer was simple and straightforward. I changed my code accordingly and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Store in an array the functions used to create your promise (not the *actual* promise itself).

Then iterate through every one, call the function that will create your promise (and run it) and wait for that batch to complete. Once, the batch is complete, move on to the next one.

```js
//function to create a promise
function p(id){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(id);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
  });  
}

const promises = [[p,p,p], [p,p], [p], [p], [p,p,p,p]]

async function promiseBatchHandler(){
  for(let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++){
     const res = await Promise.all(promises[i].map((a,j)=>a(`${i}|${j}`)))
     console.log(res);
  }
}

promiseBatchHandler();
```